# What is a MULTILINESTRING25D

Tags: ogr

I've never encountered the OGR geometry type MULTILINESTRING25D before (or any of the *25D types). What are these? How do they differ from other types? I couldn't find any useful documentation from the rest of the internet.

Comment: Perhaps this post might help: [Clarification of the “25D” option in ogr2ogr](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7852/clarification-of-the-25d-option-in-ogr2ogr)